# to find new lines character in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Having couple of entries in database table that have multiple line "names" data. 
I try to find single newline character from it.

```
SELECT
   id,
   strpos ( NAME, E'\n' ) AS Position_of_substring
FROM
   problems
WHERE
   strpos ( NAME, E'\n' ) > 0;
```

But it fails for the data that have more than 1 new line character (\n).
ANy way to find "n" number of "\n" in names data.

Comment: What output do you expect? If `id` has multiple newlines do you need to show the position of each newline?

Answer (score 3):

`regexp_matches` will emit a row for each match. [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html)

```
SELECT
   id,
   strpos ( NAME, E'\n' ) AS Position_of_substring
FROM
   problems p
WHERE
   (select count(*) from regexp_matches(p.name,E'\n','g') ) = ?;
```

Comment: what "?" stands for in your answer

Comment: number of newline matches( 0,1,2...n)
Since you did not state what exactly you need I created SQL to find `id`s that has N number of newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

This one gives you a list of all indexes with `\n` in your string. I am not sure if you were expecting this result:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c940be219a0fe667aad4403364dc56c5)

```
SELECT
    name,
    array_remove(                -- 5
        (array_agg(sum))::int[], -- 4
        length(name) + 1        
    )
FROM (
    -- 3
    SELECT 
        name, 
        SUM(length(lines) + 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY row_number)
    FROM (
        -- 2
        SELECT 
            *,
            row_number() OVER ()
        FROM (
            -- 1
            SELECT 
                name, 
                regexp_split_to_table(name, '\n') as lines 
            FROM problems
        )s
    )s
) s
GROUP BY name
```

1. Splitting the string at the `\n` chars. Every split part is now one row in a temporary table.
2. Adding a `row_count` to assure the right order of the split parts
3. This counts the length of all single split parts. The (length + 1) gives the position of the `\n`. The [`SUM` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) sums up all values within a group (your original text). That's why the order is relevant. For example: The first two parts of *"abc\nde\nfgh"* have the lengths of 3 and 2. So the breaks are at 4 (*abc* = 3, + 1) and 3 (*de* = 2, + 1). But the 3 of the second part is no real index, but if you sum up these values you get the right indexes: 4 and 7.
4. Aggregating these results
5. If (as in my example) the last char is always a `\n` and you are only interested in the `\n` chars the string you could remove the last entry of the aggregated array.

---

**Changed problem in comments below:**

> Would like to replace \n with spaces. So I am thinking how above query
>   will look in the Update statement. – Pranav Unde

Replacing the `\n` by spaces is a quiet different problem then getting indexes for all occurances of a special character. And it's much simpler:

```
UPDATE problems  
SET name = trim(regexp_replace(name, E'\n', ' ', 'g'));
```

1. `regexp_replace(..., 'g')` finds all occurances of `\n` and does the replacing
2. `trim()` removes the whitespaces before and after the string if necessary (maybe because there was a trailing `\n` as in my example - which was replaced by a space as well in the step before)

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=123d7ab329eb48332a3bd699a7c9f14d)

Comment: Query works for me to find out. How would be Update statement but? should I insert REPLACE statement in it?

Comment: Would like to replace \n with spaces. So I am thinking how above query will look in the Update statement.

Comment: That's the reason why it is always better to tell the whole use case. Replacing is much simpler than getting the indexes. See expanded answer.